# Split/break up a long HTML file? Do I use PHP include?

Tags: php, html

What is the convention for breaking up a long HTML file?

I am currently using `<?php include("storage"); ?>` and putting all the code in a file call "storage" with the extension removed so it cannot be accessed by visitors to my site. This is probably not right.

Comment: Ya that's not right, so what you exactly need? and if you really want your file not to be accessed by users use .`htaccess` to secure your files

Comment: `include` - yes, "remove extension so it can't be accessed" - LOL. Move your files out of the webroot folder to protect them from direct access. If this is your primary question, there are many similar ones here already.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Files without extensions work just fine. PHP does not need or care about file extensions.

Comment: @deceze haha never tried without extensions, so what if I am having 2 files say `demo.html` and `demo.php` and am using `include("demo");` so which 1 will it take?

Comment: @Mr.Alien He's not just omitting it from the `include`, the *actual file* does not have an extension.

Comment: @deceze hahaha got it...

Comment: having a PHP file without an extension is even more dangerous, as it will NOT be processed by the server. hence should anyone 'guess' your filename, he could just download your server side code

Comment: What problem is breaking up the large file supposed to solve?

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I am used to developing nodeJS apps where all the javascript can be broken into pieces for easy management. I find it hard to work with long 1 page html document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that breaking up a long HTML file is in itself conventional enough to warrant a convention for how to do it. There is no gain to the end user, the same size chunk of HTML will have to be passed in a single request.

Is this only for your convenience while developing? In that case I would prefer a build script that combined the files before deploying them, rather than having to combine them at server side for each request.

However, if the file is so big that you can't work in it efficiently, you should probably consider if that's something you want to send to the user at each request.

As others have pointed out, there's nothing specific about removing file extensions that protects them from being accessed by the user, unless you explicitly configure your server to do that.

Comment: Its only for my convenience. I guess I will continue using php-include for now, and then go back and cut + paste everything before serving it up to users. The html is big and hard to work with because there is a lot of text in it. Thanks!